# Arrayが期待される変数同士を足し合わせるとき、片方がnilの可能性がある場合の書き方

Tags: ruby

Array同士を足し合わせるときに、`+` が使えるかと思うのですが、しかし、片方が`nil`だった場合に、`+`を行おうとすると、エラーが起きてしまいます。また似たようなメソッドであるところの`concat`も同じように`nil`が入ってくるとエラーが入ってくるかと思わます。

そこで、ある変数が二つあるとして、この片方が`nil`である可能性がある場合に、これらを安全に合わせたいと思っています。書き方としては、以下のような書き方があることはわかっています。

以下の事例では`a`は必ずArrayがセットされており、`b`には`nil`が入っている可能性がある場合とします:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = nil # わかりやすくnilをセット

c = a + b.to_a
p c
# output: [1, 2, 3]

c = b.nil? ? a : a + b
p c
# output: [1, 2, 3]

c = a.concat b || []
p c
# output: [1, 2, 3]
```

とはいえ、もっとダイレクトに`nil`の可能性があってもArray同士を足し合わせることができる方法がありそうな気がしたのですが、もしそのような方法があれば教えて下さい

Comment: `a` のほうが nil である可能性は考慮しなくて良いのですか?
良いのなら、その旨を記載しておいたほうが良さそうです。

Comment: その通りですね、趣旨が伝わりやすいように本文を修正しました

Answer (score 8, accepted):

長めだけど、 map/reduce 感があるのでわかりやすいかも。

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = nil
c = [3, 4, 5]
d = [nil]; 

[a, b, c, d].compact.reduce(:+) # 重複あり
# => [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, nil]

[a, b, c, d].compact.reduce(:|) # 重複なし
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, nil]
```

Comment: 古めの ruby の場合は、`.reduce(:+)` のかわりに　`.inject([], :+)` を使ってください。意味は同じです。

Comment: `reduce`と、`inject`にシンボル渡す記法は1.8.7以降で有効ですね。あと、`inject`もinitパラメータを省略できるように同時になっているので、`.inject(:+)` と書いても平気。

Answer (score 3):

stackoverflow に次の QA がありました。

- Merge arrays if not nil and not empty  
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228709/merge-arrays-if-not-nil-and-not-empty

そこには２つの方法が示されていました。

```
a = [1,2,3]
b =nil

# 回答 1
p [a, b].compact.reduce([], :|)  # => [1, 2, 3]
p [b, a].compact.reduce([], :|)  # => [1, 2, 3]

# 回答 2
p Array(a) | Array(b)  # => [1, 2, 3]
p Array(b) | Array(a)  # => [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

`a + b.to_a` ではいかがでしょうか。
`nil.to_a` は `[]` を返し、配列の `to_a` は自分自身を返します。

Comment: 個人的には `to_a` で十分かなとは感じていますが、
この例は質問内にて示されています。

Answer (score 1):

配列が入れ子になっていないと仮定できるなら `Array#flatten` と `Array#compact` を続けて使うのがスッキリしてよさそうです。

```
irb(main):001:0> a = [1, 2]
=> [1, 2]
irb(main):002:0> b = nil
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> a + b
TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into Array
    from (irb):3:in `+'
    from (irb):3
    from /Users/mitsuhiro.takano/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
irb(main):004:0> c = a | b
TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into Array
    from (irb):4:in `|'
    from (irb):4
    from /Users/mitsuhiro.takano/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
irb(main):005:0> [a, b]
=> [[1, 2], nil]
irb(main):006:0> [a, b].flatten
=> [1, 2, nil]
irb(main):007:0> [a, b].flatten.compact
=> [1, 2]
```